# WordPress - child theme styling and rapid composer

Tags: wordpress

I have heard that styling changes that aren't made in a `styles.css` folder in the child theme are lost/deleted when you update the theme.

I am wondering if this is true for changes I make with visual composer, or otherwise through WordPress tools. E.g. I just changed a font color with visual composer, but as I understand it, this just edits the parent theme CSS file hence my concerns!

Any tips please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that if you change the color via the `VC` you will lose that change when you update the theme. The `VC` changes the color via inline css so you should be good.

Comment: Thanks!! Appreciate it. Check for the inline comment that's good to know

Answer (score 1):

Changes that you make with WordPress tools such as Visual Composer will not be lost when you update the plugin or theme. A quick solution to add some CSS to your site if you want to avoid creating a child theme is to use a plugin such as [Simple Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/).

Comment: Thanks!! Appreciate it